# Trying to get a react-app that's not mine to work which cannot find a localhost url

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react app that isn't mine (a former employee) and I'm still quite new to react. I need to get the app to work so it retrieves data from a SQL database. At the moment the app can't find a request URL from itself called `http://localhost//FleetManagement//Api/Default.aspx?method=GetCustomers`

The react app gives the following error:

[image]

Or in text:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
(anonymous function)
C:/CodeRacvsolar/react-app/src/App.tsx:201
  198 | 
  199 | api.getCustomers(
  200 |   (req: XMLHttpRequest) => {
> 201 |     let getCustomersResponse: interfaces.GetCustomersResponse = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
  202 | ^
  203 |     this.setState({
  204 |       data: getCustomersResponse,
View compiled

XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange
C:/CodeRacvsolar/react-app/src/api/api.tsx:54
  51 | 
  52 |        if (req.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) { 
  53 |            if (onComplete) {
> 54 |                onComplete(req)
  55 | ^          }
  56 |        }
  57 |
```

Comment: Is the API server running on the same localhost port? If not, you can start the API server on a different port and add that as a proxy to your react app package.json.

Comment: It looks like your react app is expecting a JSON response from the API but it's not a valid JSON. Can you post the actual response of `http://localhost//FleetManagement//Api/Default.aspx?method=GetCustomers'?

Comment: there was no response i tihnk this is the issue,

Comment: Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 4904
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 22 Mar 2022 22:07:50 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 this is the response headers

Comment: ok so i beleive i know what ive done wrong, i need an iss server for asp.net, if this sounds wrong please let me know